# How to determine if litecoin address is valid

Tags: php, string

I need a way in php to check if a string is a valid litecoin address. It does not need to check if the litecoin address actually exists, but that it is not invalid (wrong length, non hex characters etc...).

Comment: So, what is a litecoin? What is the format it uses for addresses? How is it normally validated? What have you tried? I'm sure we could google this stuff, but we are not here to google it for you.

Comment: As of now i have only set the criteria that the string be no less than 34 and no more than 36 characters in length, must start with L, and not contain hex invalid characters... Are there other criteria that makes up a Litecoin address?  (A litecoin is a crypto-currency much like bitcoin but based on scrypt... https://litecoin.org/)  I am not asking for google, i have searched around, and as far as i could tell there are three criterias: length, hex valid characters and must start with L... I am simply asking if i have missed some other criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is using regular expressions, there are several available online, the one used below comes from [regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com)

```
// the regular expression
$pattern = '/^L[a-zA-Z0-9]{26,33}$/';

// should fail 
$subject = "1EEVBLgg4h4TTLv76QiQ1Thcvvk3Be7VPV";
echo $subject . ' matches? ' . (preg_match($pattern, $subject) == 0 ? 'nope' : 'yup') . "\n";

// should pass
$subject = "Lg6GPVfPsmPAbTWYuKBQXtdGnBuCWcxHcr";
echo  $subject . ' matches? ' . (preg_match($pattern, $subject) == 0 ? 'nope' : 'yup') . "\n";
```

That regex is close but not entirely correct as it allows all alpha & 0 to pass, the one below is stricter:

```
// the improved regular expression
$pattern = '/^L[a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{26,33}$/';
```

excludes `0OIl` that are excluded from Base58Check for optimized readability.

Comment: Because this answer is now obsolete. Check answer by @YuyaOgawa and its comment.

Answer (score 12):

Litecoin address starts with L or M or 3, so Regex should be below

```
$pattern = '/^[LM3][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{26,33}$/';
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer nowadays given Litecoin has introduced M-addresses (P2SH Segwit) to migrate away from the 3-addresses (P2SH non-Segwit) to avoid confusion with bitcoin that also uses 3-addresses. The L-addresses are also still valid (legacy P2PKH).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JSON RPC](http://jsonrpcphp.org/).

Something like this should work:

```
$valid = $ltc->validateaddress($address);
if($valid['isvalid'] == "true") {
    echo "Valid address";
}
else {
    echo "Invalid address";
}
```

[See more examples](https://litecointalk.org/index.php?topic=1437.0)

If this is not sufficient then I guarantee that this has been solved somewhere else, you might just need the right keywords in the search engines.

Answer (score 2):

for mainnet ltc addresses

```
/^([LM3]{1}[a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{26,33}||ltc1[a-z0-9]{39,59})$/;
```

if you don't want to understand the details you can skip the rest of the part

Breaking it down

For regular addresses

```
[LM3]{1}
```

address will start with L, M or 3, {1} defines that only match one character in square bracket

```
/[13]{1}[a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]/
```

cannot have l (small el), I (capital eye), O (capital O) and 0 (zero)

```
/[13]{1}[a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{26,33}/
```

can be 27 to 34 characters long, remember we already checked the first character to be 1 or 3, so remaining address will be 26 to 33 characters long

For segwit

```
ltc1
```

starts with ltc1

```
/ltc1[a-z0-9]/
```

can only contain lower case letters and numbers

```
/ltc1[a-z0-9]{39,59}/
```

can be 43 to 63 characters long, we already checked first three characters to be ltc1, so remaining address will be 39 to 59 characters long

Comment: Do you have an example of an address longer than 43 characters? we've been validating segwit addresses with: /^ltc1[a-zA-HJ-NP-Z0-9]{25,40}$/
Never got any complaints from users who couldn't register their wallet address, but the problem we have is that the address is not completely validated and we are getting invalid addresses registered with this, looking for a stricter validation.

Answer (score 1):

@yuya-ogawa regex covers litecoin's mainnet addresses fully.

If you want to include testnet addresses as well though:

`/^[LM3Q2mn][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{26,34}$/`

This additionally includes:

- p2pkh addresses which are same as bitcoin and start with `m` or `n`
- and also p2sh addresses which start with `2` (old) and `Q` (new).

Answer (score 0):

```
ltc1qkehw26l582teu5ryqqe9jzs4cph4wspvnq0smm
```

this address not match...

https://www.regextester.com/99712

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried [this code](https://github.com/MadCapsule/Litecoin-PHP-Library/blob/master/litecoin.php) but perhaps it can help:

```
 /**
   * Determine if a string is a valid Litecoin address
   *
   * @author theymos
   * @param string $addr String to test
   * @param string $addressversion
   * @return boolean
   * @access public
   */
  public static function checkAddress($addr, $addressversion = LITECOIN_ADDRESS_VERSION) {
    $addr = self::decodeBase58($addr);
    if (strlen($addr) != 50) {
      return false;
    }
    $version = substr($addr, 0, 2);
    if (hexdec($version) > hexdec($addressversion)) {
      return false;
    }
    $check = substr($addr, 0, strlen($addr) - 8);
    $check = pack("H*", $check);
    $check = strtoupper(hash("sha256", hash("sha256", $check, true)));
    $check = substr($check, 0, 8);
    return $check == substr($addr, strlen($addr) - 8);
  }
```